# Broken relative url in css

Tags: html, css

In every css from external projects I have to replace url like this:

```
url(image.jpg)
```

to

```
url(../image.jpg)
```

Maybe that's connected with the way I have to include css with trailing slash:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/project1/style.css/"  th:href="@{ /project1/style.css/ }" />
```

Comment: My first suspect would be a `<base href>`. Do you have any `base` tags in the generated code?

Comment: could you please point me out a direction to find out whats is th:href="@{ /css/style.css/ }" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include the extra `/`

**Try this:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"   th:href="@{ /css/style.css }" />
```

Comment: you could even try without first slash too

Comment: thanks, It wasn't working without trailing slash before, now it works.